# Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin and update packages

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I've just created a new `Cross-Platform` project in `Visual Studio 2017`. There are some packages to update.

[image: Packages to update]

If I try to update those packages, unfortunately, I receive an error:

> Installing Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.1.7. Signature
>   Hash Algorithm: SHA256 NU3008: The package integrity check failed.
>   Signature type: Author Timestamp: 12/06/2018 01:27:08
>
> Verifying timestamp with timestamping service certificate:  Subject
>   Name: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping Signer - G2, OU=Symantec Trust
>   Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US SHA1 hash:
>   625AEC3AE4EDA1D169C4EE909E85B3BBC61076D3 SHA256 hash:
>   CF7AC17AD047ECD5FDC36822031B12D4EF078B6F2B4C5E6BA41F8FF2CF4BAD67
>   Issued by: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping CA, OU=Symantec Trust
>   Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US Valid from: 02/01/2017 00:00:00
>   to 02/04/2028 00:59:59
>
> Verifying signature with author certificate:  Subject Name:
>   CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond,
>   S=Washington, C=US SHA1 hash: F404000FB11E61F446529981C7059A76C061631E
>   SHA256 hash:
>   3F9001EA83C560D712C24CF213C3D312CB3BFF51EE89435D3430BD06B5D0EECE
>   Issued by: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA,
>   OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US Valid from: 26/02/2018
>   00:00:00 to 27/01/2021 12:00:00

[image: Update Xamarin solution]

What can I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I too have the same issue with my Visual Studio 2017, have you found any solution to this?